# run glue container locally using docker-compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, aws-glue

I would like to run `REPL shell (Pyspark)` from the glue container using this command `$ docker run -it -v ~/.aws:/home/glue_user/.aws -e AWS_PROFILE=$PROFILE_NAME -e DISABLE_SSL=true --rm -p 4040:4040 -p 18080:18080 --name glue_pyspark amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_3.0.0_image_01 pyspark`  mentioned in [pyspark-glue-container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html) but instead of running as `docker run` I would like to run as `docker-compose`. Hence created below compose file:

```
container_name: "glue_container"
image: amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_2.0.0_image_01
environment:
  DISABLE_SSL: "true"
ports:
  - 4040:40404
  - 18080:18080
command: pyspark
volumes:
  - ${PWD}/local_path_to_workspace:/home/glue_user/workspace/
```

but I'm not able to get the glue pyspark shell up and running? but the container is exiting with an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you got a "volume must be a mapping" error

Try this format

```
services:
  pyspark_repl:
    image: amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_2.0.0_image_01
    environment:
      DISABLE_SSL: "true"
    ports:
      - 4040:40404
      - 18080:18080
    command: pyspark
    volumes: 
      - ${PWD}:/home/glue_user/workspace/
```

Then run it like this

```
docker-compose run --rm pyspark_repl
```

Comment: No, I'm getting pyspark_repl exit 0...also when I ran the `docker run` command as suggested I see it uses `bash -lc pyspark` in `docker ps` command. If I made the same change in my docker-compose with entry point as `bash` and command as -c "pyspark"  it also doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, i got that volume error when I ran your compose file.   Did you try my compose file format?

Comment: yes, I confirm the `ocker-compose run --rm pyspark_repl` is the only way you can get the pyspark commondline... don't know why it doesn't work in docker-compose even if I delete the volume mount.